# Angularjs: Able to log data but cannot display

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I am attempting to create a form that upon clicking submit calls a function that will post to a php page (which runs a query), then displays those results on the page.

If I call said function in my controller on load, I get my expected result(data presented in html table in a modal).  However if I call that function upon clicking submit. I can log the data result, but it does not display on my page.

```js
  $scope.report = {};
  var url = "";
  // calling our submit function.
  $scope.submitForm = function() {

      $http.post('url.php').success(function(data) {
          // Stored the returned data into scope 
          $scope.names = data;
          console.log(data);
          $('#myModal').modal();
      });
  };
```

```html
<button type = "button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="submitForm()" >Submit Request</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" >
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content" >
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
               <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
               </tr>
               <tr ng-repeat="name in names | filter:search_query">
                  <td><span>{{name.first}}</span></td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: first print you {{names}} on html view page and see the structure of the result. post the result is possible.

Comment: I am not able to print the data result {{names}} to the page.  I get the same results as if I were trying to display inside a modal.. However if I call the function onLoad rather than onSubmit, both work

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a small `$timeout` before opening your modal (don't forget to inject `$timeout` to your controller):

```
$scope.submitForm = function() {

      $http.post('url.php').success(function(data) {
          // Stored the returned data into scope 
          $scope.names = data;
          console.log(data);

          $timeout(function () {
              $('#myModal').modal();
          },250);
      });
  };
```

Comment: I am still getting original results.. I also tried just displaying the data on the page in a table rather than in a modal.. Can console.log(data) just fine, but no results are displayed on the page

Comment: @dallas could you give the format of the logged data? Have you checked if `$scope.names` has the desired format?

Comment: If I console.log(data) I get an array of objects in the format -                  
0
:
Object
First
:
"John"

Comment: and does it have the property `first` that you are trying to access by `{{name.first}}`?